# Usage of that regardless/ that nothwithstanding

Tags: phrase-usage

Is it grammatically correct to use the phrase **that regardless** or **that notwithstanding** at the beginning of a sentence

> That irregardless, the victim failed to adduced evidence
>
> That notwithstanding, the victim failed to adduce evidence

Comment: It's a bit "unusual" (but not "ungrammatical") to start an utterance with ***That notwithstanding*** (where ***that*** obviously references some immediately-preceding utterance. We'd much much likely say ***Notwithstanding this***. But note that the somewhat less common ***irregardless*** requires a preposition, so it would have to be [***irregardless of this.***](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22irregardless+of+this%22%22) And many/most people wouldn't approve of ***irregardless*** anyway. Stick with ***Regardless of this***.

Comment: I think I would have usually used _Nevertheless the victim ..." but either of @FumbleFingersReinstateMonica suggestion work too. I would have to say I have never seen or heard _irregardless_ so it may be a quite rare word.

Comment: All these 50-cent words! What's wrong with plain old ***however***? Or even more plain ***but***, after changing the period at the end of the preceding sentence to a comma.

Comment: irregardless: "this word is widely regarded as nonstandard and incorrect."